# what's the difference between Eisenstat trick and an implicit preconditioner?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Assume ${A}$ is Hermitian positive definite and $\hat A$=$D^{-1/2}$$A$$D^{-1/2}$ is to obtain a symmetric variant.
and $M$=($L_{A}$+$D$)$D^{-1}$($D$+$U_{A}$) where $D$ is a suitable diagonal matrix and $A$= $L_{A}$+$U_{A}$+$D_{A}$, so how much faster would the CG code to be with this $\hat A$ of the Eisenstat trick as compared to using $M$ as an implicit preconditioner?
could anyone clarify this， in short it should compare the speed between the DILU preconditioner and Eisenstat trick?